# Get and list users based on idempresa of logged in user

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard

I want to get & list all the users that belongs to the same `idempresa` that the user logged in has. `idempresa` is related to users in a `sf_guard_profile` table and yes I have the relation declared on `schema.yml` file. I think in write a method in `sfGuardUserTable.class.php` but I'm not so sure it will works in others words I don't know where to touch or what to handle this. Can any point me in the right direction on this? This is the method (unfinished):

```
public function getUsersByCompany() {
        $user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getProfile()->getIdEmpresa();
        $q = $this->createQuery('g');

        return $q;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not good practice to use sfContext::getInstance(). Read this post http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/.

How about adding a static method to your `sfGuardUserTable.class.php`, e.g

```
// \lib\form\sfGuardUserTable.class.php
static public function getUsersByIdEmpresa($idempresa)
{
    //...
    $q->andWhere('idempressa = ?', $idempresa);

    return $q->execute(); 
}
```

Then calling it in your controller or from where you need, e.g

```
// \app\myApp\modules\myModule\actions\action.class.php
public function executeMyAction() {
    $profile = $this->getUser()->getProfile();
    $usersRelatedByIdempresa = sfGuardUserTable::getUsersByIdempresa($profile->getIdempresa());

    //...
}
```

Comment: get your point but I get lost, if I'm talking about `sfDoctrineGuard` plugin then you say that I must overwrite the method `executeIndex()` under `admin/modules/sfGuardUser/actions`?

Comment: That was just an example of how you can call it in a controller. You don't have to overwrite the sfGuardUser actions.